# How is my variable changing value during the return statement in a recursive algorithm?

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list

I am doing an exercise with linked lists in Javascript. As part of my solution, I have a function that takes a linked list of one digit integers and converts it to a single number. The value being returned is not the same as the value logged to the console the line before the return.

for example, if I input `(2 -> 4 -> 3)`, my console.log is `342`, just as it should, but the value returned in `otherFunction` is `386`. Input `(5 -> 6 -> 4)` logs `465`, but returns `535`.

How is the value of `num` changing?

```
function parseListNumber(list, num = 0, multiplier = 1) {
    digitValue = list.val * multiplier;
    multiplier *= 10;
    num += digitValue;
    if (list.next) {
        return num + parseListNumber(list.next, num, multiplier);
    } else {
        console.log(num) // num is correct here
        return num;
    }
}

function otherFunction(list) {
    parseListNumber(list); // returned value is now somehow larger
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding `num` to your recursive call each time you enter your `if` statement. If you remove this, then when you hit your *base case*, your value will be carried back up through the previous recursive calls and remain unchanged.

See example below:

```js
const list = {
  val: 2,
  next: {
    val: 4,
    next: {
      val: 3
    }
  }
};

function parseListNumber(list, num = 0, multiplier = 1) {
  let digitValue = list.val * multiplier;
  multiplier *= 10;
  num += digitValue;
  if (list.next) {
    return parseListNumber(list.next, num, multiplier); // remove `num +` (use tail recursion)
  } else {
    console.log(num) // num is correct here
    return num;
  }
}

function otherFunction(list) {
  console.log("Actual res: ", parseListNumber(list));
};

otherFunction(list);
```